# ORA-12528: TNS Listener: all appropriate instances are blocking new connections. Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN

Tags: database, oracle, database-administration

I'm getting this error if i try to login as db user. If `lsnrctl` status is run i get the below error.
 DB was working fine all these years and stopped working suddenly.

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=ABC.LOCAL)(PORT=1521)
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                19-MAY-2014 12:18:17
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 22 min. 51 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   D:\Oracle\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         d:\oracle\administrator\diag\tnslsnr\abc\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ABC.LOCAL)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "devdb" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "devdb", status BLOCKED, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "testdb" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "testdb", status BLOCKED, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Comment: Is there anything helpful in your database and/or listener alert log? With two databases blocking I'd wonder if you had a common filesystem that had run out of space, perhaps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to know if the problem come from the listener or from the database.

- So first, restart the listener, it could solve the problem.
- Second, it could come from the db if it's not in open mode (nomount, mount, restrict). To check it, connect locally and do the following query:

  sqlplus /nolog

  connect / as sysdba

  SQL> select instance_name, status, database_status from v$instance;

Comment: Tried sqlplus /no log connect sys/password as sysdba but getting ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Comment: Did you set the SID?  set ORACLE_SID=<sid>

Comment: It is an existing database and i can't query v$ table to find SID. However in my pc tns name says for example HOST=DBSERVER.EUR.LOCAL i guess i can use it as SID.

Comment: @shady - host is the machine name. From your `lsnrctl` output, try `devdb` or `testdb`.

Comment: Oh thanks, i tried setting the SID to TESTDB but still throwing same error. If i try to connect It gives same old ORA-12560 TNS protocol adapter error.

Answer (score 17):

```
set ORACLE_SID=<YOUR_SID>
sqlplus "/as sysdba"
alter system disable restricted session;
```

or maybe

```
shutdown abort;
```

or maybe

```
lsnrctl stop

lsnrctl start
```

Comment: Tried both listener restart, server restart and manually restarted machine still getting same error.

Comment: And your alert log has what entries in it?

Answer (score 4):

I had this error message with boot2docker on windows with the docker-oracle-xe-11g image (https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/wnameless/oracle-xe-11g/).

The reason was that the virtual box disk was full (check with `boot2docker.exe ssh df`). Deleting old images and restarting the container solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem on my developent environment with Visual Studio.

What helped me was to `Clean Solution` in Visual Studio and then do a rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 11G XE with Windows, along with tns listener restart, make sure Windows Event Log service is started.

Answer (score 1):

I tried restarting my computer and that fixed it for me.